# Default value in WPF Settings as `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`

Tags: c#, wpf

Recently, I have been working on a WPF application, and I have been adding user settings to the project. For one of the settings, `SaveDir`, I need the default value to be the returning string of the method `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`.

[SaveDir in Visual Studio designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul9Yn.png)

I had a look at the code behind the designer in visual studio, and found this:

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
public string SaveDir {
    get {
        return ((string)(this["SaveDir"]));
    }
    set {
        this["SaveDir"] = value;
    }
}
```

I tried to remove the quotes in the `System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute` to the method `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, but that raised the following error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

How can I set the default value of this setting to the current directory of the application?

When the application starts I update the setting like this:

```
Settings.Default.SaveDir = 
Directory.Exists(Settings.Default.SaveDir)
    ? Settings.Default.SaveDir
    : Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

This gives me some issues when the user resets all settings. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Why use a setting for this over `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() `directly? Settings are meant to store configurable values, not for reading environmental state.

Comment: The setting will store a directory (the user will change this according to their preferences), but the default value is `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`.

Comment: If you *really* need it, use an empty string to represent "no value".  Use an `if` check to look at the current setting at startup and set it to `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` if it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That actually won't work. You cannot set the value of the setting `SaveDir` to `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`.

However, there are a couple of ways around this. When you call `Settings.Default.Reset()`, In the same method you can re-run the code which sets the value of `SaveDir`.

```
void ResetMySettings
{
    // Method where settings are reset
    Properties.Settings.Default.Reset();

    // Set value of SaveDir
    CheckSaveDirValue();
}

...

private void CheckSaveDirValue()
{
    Settings.Default.SaveDir = 
        Directory.Exists(Settings.Default.SaveDir)
        ? Settings.Default.SaveDir
        : Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
}
```

However, this is not a good idea. You do not want to let the end user use the application directory, what if they accidentally delete a `.dll` file?

The best thing to do is create another application directory in which you store all of your user's files.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create a class that wraps the configuration attributes that users can change, and add some control of empty or null values.

This will allow you to create properties and return default values when needed:

```
public class MyAppSettings
{
    public string SaveDir
    { 
        get
        {
            if(Properties.Settings.Default.SaveDir.Equals(String.Empty))
            {
                return Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            }
            return Properties.Settings.Default.SaveDir;
        }
   }
}
```

Changing or modifying auto-generated code can be a bit risky as you risk the IDE changing it unexpectedly.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to set default value to wrong property name `DefaultSaveDir`, it should be '`SaveDir`'

```
Settings.Default.SaveDir = 
Directory.Exists(Settings.Default.SaveDir)
    ? Settings.Default.SaveDir
    : Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

Settings.Default.Save() //<-- call save to keep the default value
```

**UPDATE:**

May be you can hook on to this event, reset the default value

```
    Settings.Default.PropertyChanged += (o, e1) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e1.PropertyName);
    };
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry about this, in my application the setting is called `DefaultSaveDir`, but in the question I changed the variable name to `SaveDir` to avoid confusion. I want to set the default value of that setting to the returning string of `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`, and also be that value when I call `Settings.Default.Reset()`. (Is there an event to run that every time the settings are reset?)